# Loop data every 20 seconds instead of showing all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out the best way to loop through this data, right now I'm getting all 'Job Names' that are the id of 6 from my API. What I'd like to do is only show one at a time for 20 seconds or so, then move to the next only showing one at a time but continuously looping through all.

Any suggestions?

Here is one api call getting the titles of Job Names:

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class Title extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <div className="Title">
          {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
            <div key = {item}>
              <h2>
                {data["data"][item][6].value}
              </h2>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Title;
```

UPDATE: So after some researching I'm seeing some ideas on what I'm looking to do. like so:

```js
let data = ['Job Name 1',
            'Job Name 2',
            'Job Name 3',
            'Job Name 4',
            'Job Name 5',
            'Job Name 6',
            'Job Name 7', 
            'Job Name 8', 
            'Job Name 9', 
            'Job Name 10'];

let interval = 2000; //I'll set to twenty seconds in production...
data.forEach((data, index) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(data)
  }, index * interval)
})
```

Similar to this, but Set this to loop continuously, so after 10, go back to 1. Is this where I'd use setInterval() instead of setTimeout()?

Once I get this set in accurately, I'd like to set LineCharts up that will populate based on what Title(Job Name) is displaying, changing when the Title does automatically...

**UPDATE** wanted to update to show How i've set the cycle in for my Job Names in my App.js, and sending this as a prop to my Title.js:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './App.css'
import Title from './components/header/Title'
import TotalLineChart from './components/charts/TotalLineChart'
import RadiantLineChart from './components/charts/RadiantLineChart'
import PlumbingLineChart from './components/charts/PlumbingLineChart'
import SnowmeltLineChart from './components/charts/SnowmeltLineChart'
import HVACLineChart from './components/charts/HVACLineChart'
import GasPipeLineChart from './components/charts/GasPipeLineChart'
import FixturesLineChart from './components/charts/FixturesLineChart'
// import TitleCycle from './components/TitleCycle'
// import Logo from './components/Logo';

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Retry-After": 120000
};

function App() {
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  // Fetch all data, all jobs
  useEffect(() => {
      function fetchData() {
          let body = {
              from: "bpz99ram7",
              select: [3, 6, 40],
              where: "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}",
              sortBy: [{ fieldId: 6, order: "ASC" }],
              groupBy: [{ fieldId: 40, grouping: "equal-values" }],
              options: { skip: 0, top: 0, compareWithAppLocalTime: false },
          };
          fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(({ data }) => setAllData(data));
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);

// Cycle through the jobIds and indexes
useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
        () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % allData.length),
        5000 // 5 seconds.
    );
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
}, [allData]);
// console.log(allData)
// console.log(index)
// Calculate info based on index
const jobId = allData[index]?.['3']?.value || '291'; // Default 291
const title = allData[index]?.['6']?.value || 'Default Title'; 
// console.log(jobId)
  return (
      <div>
        {/* <div className="flexbox-container">
          <div className="Logo">
          {/* <Logo /> */}
         {/* </div> */}
        <div className="App">
          <Title title = {title} />
        </div>
        <div className="TopChart">
          <TotalLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div>
        <div className="FirstRowContainer">
          {/* <RadiantLineChart jobId = {jobId} /> */}
          <PlumbingLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <FixturesLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div>
        <div className="SecondRowContainer">
          <SnowmeltLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <HVACLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
          <GasPipeLineChart jobId = {jobId} />
        </div> 
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Title.js**

```
import React from 'react'

function Title(props) {
  const { title } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      { title }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Title
```

This allows the cycle and show one at a time based on the duration set in App.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your data looks like, but below is my closest guess.

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class Title extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
      displayItem : ''
    };

    this.dataInterval;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  startShowingData(data) {
    let counter = 0;
    
    let dataKeys = Object.keys(data["data"])
    this.dataInterval = setInterval(() => {
          this.setState({...this.state, displayItem: data[dataKeys[counter]]});
          counter++; // you have to reset this counter at your wish or you have to do clearInterval(this.dataInterval) after array is completely traversed.
      }, 20000)
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.startShowingData(data.data));
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <div className="Title">
              <h2>
                {this.state.displayItem}
              </h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Title;
```

Comment: Right now I'm getting a list of Job names. So just want to loop through these instead of showing all at once. I'll give this a shot, thanks icebug!

Comment: So we are setting displayItem to state as blank correct? I'm getting an error as unexpected token for ```displayItem = ''```

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `displayItem: ''` rather than `displayItem = ''`, edited the answer

Comment: Can't seem to work around an error on line 19 - ```this.dataInterval;``` ```Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression```